# position element to the right of another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have an dropdown menu like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <button id="showMe">
  <ul id="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Blah</li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

The #container div has `position: 'relative'` and `#drop-down` has `position: 'absolute'`, how can I position the #dropdown-menu in such a way that the right of the element is at the right of the #container element.  They should be right aligned with #container at the top and #dropdown-menu directly below but right aligned?

Comment: you need to use position relative ? because I would do it either with float or with box-sizing

Comment: You have an unordered list, if it's somehow a dropdown, or you're using a plugin to create a dropdown, you have to tell us how and what ?

Comment: `left: 100%;` will align it to the right

Answer (score 0):

set left of the that element equals to minus(width of the container) and top to the minus(height of the container)

```
 top:-height_of_container;
 left:-width_of_the_conatiner;
```